# Comparison Operators: Pattern for fewest lines

Tags: design-patterns, overloading, operator-keyword

I've been told that it is possible to write 6 comparison operators ( < , <= , > , >= , == , != ) based on the definition of just one. The pattern supposedly starts with a strict inequality. < for example. By negating <, you can define >=, since they are opposites. I get stuck at this point. Perhaps I am starting from the wrong operator. It's not important of course, but I'm curious. Cheers!

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just figured out the answer:

1. define a strict inequality. I.e., x < y
2. flip variables. define x > y by using y < x as definition.
3. use opposites. define x >= y as !(x < y)
4. use opposites. define x <= y as !(x > y)
5. x == y is defined as ( x <= y && x >= y)
6. x != y is defined as !(x == y)

Thanks everyone!